# Delphi, charset detection ([Uni]SynEdit) - Utf8Decode problem

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8

I'm using Unicode SynEdit, which (in theory) has basic file/stream encoding detection. It worked fine until I tried opening the file which was generated by my PHP script. The file I'm talking about is detected by UniSynEdit as utf8 with no BOM. Unfortunately, it doesn't open - the loaded string is empty. I debugged it, and it seems that the problem is the function Utf8Decode, which fails for some reason and returns empty string. I've also checked the file with hex editor, and it's true: it has no BOM, all the normal characters are encoded using one byte, while some polish letters I had in the file (like "ł") are double-byte...

What could be wrong, and how can I prevent this? I believe wrong encoding loaded is better than no file at all...

Comment: What version of Delphi are you on?

Comment: I forgot to write ... Delphi 7.

Comment: What happens when there's BOM?

Comment: If UTF8Decode() is returning an empty string, then the input is not valid UTF-8 to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to load files that are not correctly UTF-8 encoded, then you need to use a function that does not return an empty result for a string containing invalid byte sequences, but does instead replace them a replacement character. See the [Wikipedia entry on UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8), in particular the section on "Invalid byte sequences".

Unfortunately the Delphi 2009 (don't have Delphi 7 to check there) `UTF8Decode()` calls `MultibyteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, ...)` internally, which returns an error on invalid byte sequences.

What you'd have to do is to use an alternative encoding function. Maybe there's something in one of the third party Delphi libraries that have their own decoding functions. Maybe you could use one of the linked libraries [here](http://www.freebyte.com/programming/unicode/#delphiunicodelibraries). If all else fails you could write your own, maybe based on [this code](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/CVTUTF/ConvertUTF.c) from the Unicode consortium.

Comment: BTW: If you didn't even *mean* your PHP script to create a UTF-8 file - think again about that. It should, and preferably valid UTF-8 :-)

Comment: that's not a point :) actually thanks to that I found my app failing at some point, so far I was sure it handles all the **valid** files. and it does. But I had no chance to test again those invalid ;)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that using UTF8StringToWideString from cUnicodeCodecs (Delphi Fundamentals) works fine :]